# How to post base 64(Image) string in WCF rEST service

Tags: json, wcf

I am working on a WCF service and handling Image data in base64 string, while sending base64 string in json I am getting exception [System.FormatException: Encountered invalid character ] , it seems data is being serialize .

Is there any way to archive this, because I cant send data in Stream for this.

my DataContact is

```
[DataContract]
public class UploadBase64
{
[DataMember]
public int ID{get;set;}
[DataMamber]
public string Base64Image{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UrlEncode and Decode utility can be used to tweak this.

While posting data we can use HttpUtility.UrlEncode in C# or encodeURI in javascript. for encoding base64 data.

And within service we can use UrlDecode to get actual string.

This is what I am using right now.